# Bootstrap table 4 icon not displaying properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

I've made a bootstrap table in my flask app with some of the extensions as showed in the documentation. Everything works fine except for the buttons which are not displaying the icons, making them user unfriendly.
The problem is consistent across browsers (google chrome and safari), and in the app whether it's deployed locally or on the cloud (app engine)

Here is my header:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>Walrus</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.15.5/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.15.5/dist/extensions/sticky-header/bootstrap-table-sticky-header.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.15.5/dist/extensions/fixed-columns/bootstrap-table-fixed-columns.css">
  <link rel='stylesheet' type=text/css href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles.css') }}"/>
   <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->    
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/tableexport.jquery.plugin/tableExport.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/tableexport.jquery.plugin/libs/jsPDF/jspdf.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/tableexport.jquery.plugin/libs/jsPDF-AutoTable/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script> 
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.15.5/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.15.5/dist/extensions/toolbar/bootstrap-table-toolbar.min.js"></script>     
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.15.5/dist/extensions/export/bootstrap-table-export.min.js"></script>  
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.15.5/dist/extensions/multiple-sort/bootstrap-table-multiple-sort.js"></script>       
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.15.5/dist/extensions/fixed-columns/bootstrap-table-fixed-columns.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.15.5/dist/extensions/sticky-header/bootstrap-table-sticky-header.min.js"></script>
   </head>
```

And here is the script generating the table:

```
<div class="main">

              <table class='table table-hover table-bordered'
            id="table"
            data-search='true'
            data-advanced-search="true"
            data-id-table="advancedTable" 
            data-show-columns='true'
            data-show-multi-sort="true"
            data-toolbar="#toolbar"
            data-show-export="true"
            >
            </table> 

                 <script>
                $('#table').bootstrapTable({
                    columns: [
                        {% for c in my_cols %}
                        {
                    field: '{{c}}',
                    title: '{{c}}',
                    sortable: true
                    },
                    {% endfor %}
                      ],
                    data: {{my_records|safe}},
                    pagination: true,
                    sortable: true,
                    fixedColumns: true,
                    fixedNumber: 5,
                    width: "900"
                  })
                </script>
```

This is what my buttons look like: [snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doWAb.png)

Any idea how to fix it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried pressing F12 and looking at the generated page, find your buttons / icons.  Check for width defined of the row being too narrow or F12 Network log might show icon image was not found or something and/or display loading errors. In F12 debugger you can change CSS properties to make rows wider and see if that unhides them. your width of 900 might be too narrow?

Comment: @ToddN Thanks for the suggestion, yes I've used the developer tool but nothing seems wrong - the width is not the issue either, removing it doesn't change the issue.